Flutter Drift Database error: SqliteException(14):while opening the database, unable to open database file (code 14)
Kindly refer to the below link of example app given by official Drift database package for flutter .
When I run it on Windows 10 it throws below error. Can someone help me to resolve this error. I want to user Drift package to develop window application using Flutter.
Example Link.
Error log:
flutter: SqliteException(14): while opening the database, unable to open database file, unable to open database file (code 14)

Got a stack frame from package:stack_trace, where a vm or web frame was expected. This can happen if FlutterError.demangleStackTrace was not set in an environment that propagates non-standard stack traces to the framework, such as during tests.
'package:flutter/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart':
Failed assertion: line 195 pos 7: 'line != '===== asynchronous gap ===========================''

The relevant error-causing widget was:
HomePage HomePage:file:///C:/Users/AMIT/Downloads/simolus3%20drift%20develop%20examples-app/lib/main.dart:19:35

can some one help resolve this error ?
Thanks.

Did you create a database?

Hello Mr. Tim Roberts! How should I create database? The example app is running fine on Android but showing this error while running on Windows. I'm also new to this. Can you please help how to run drift based app on Windows? Thanks
